# $\Vert Ax\Vert_2\le \left(\Vert A-B\Vert_F+\Vert B\Vert_2\right)\Vert x\Vert_2?$

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, normed-spaces

Let $A, B\in \mathbb R^{m\times n}$ and $x\in \mathbb R^n$.  Is it true that
$$\Vert Ax\Vert_2\le \left(\Vert A-B\Vert_F+\Vert B\Vert_2\right)\Vert x\Vert_2?$$

where $\Vert B\Vert_2$ is a spectral norm, and $\Vert A-B\Vert_F$ is a Frobenius norm.

---

I know that $\Vert Ax \Vert_2\le \Vert A\Vert_F\Vert x\Vert_2$, and clearly
$\Vert A\Vert_F=\Vert A-B+B\Vert_F\le \Vert A-B\Vert_F + \Vert B\Vert_F$.  So $\Vert Ax\Vert_2\le (\Vert A-B\Vert_F + \Vert B\Vert_F)\Vert x\Vert_2.$  But $\Vert B\Vert_2 \le \Vert B\Vert_F$.  So I'm not able to confirm the inequality above.

Is there an alternative way to prove the above inequality?  Or can someone refute it?  Thanks a lot!

Comment: What do you mean by spectral norm? In any case if you also have that $\|Ax\|_2\leq \|A\|_2\|x\|_2$ (this will always happen if for example $\|\cdot\|_2$ is the operator norm induced by the Euclidean norm in $\Bbb{R}^2$), then you can use that $\|A-B\|_2\leq\|A-B\|_F$ to get the desired result.

Comment: @AlonsoDelfín Ah...thanks for pointing this out! By spectral norm, I did mean $\Vert B\Vert_2 = \sup_{x\ne 0} \Vert Bx \Vert_2/\Vert x\Vert_2$.  So indeed $\Vert Ax\Vert_2\le \Vert A\Vert_2\Vert x\Vert_2\le (\Vert A-B\Vert_2+\Vert B\Vert_2)\Vert x\Vert_2\le (\Vert A-B\Vert_F+\Vert B\Vert_2)\Vert x\Vert_2$.